# Are service accounts considered as users in Google Sheets API v4 usage limits?

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api, google-identity

According to the Google Sheets documentation there are [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) applicable:

- 500 requests per 100 seconds per project
- 100 requests per 100 second per user
- Limits for reads and writes are tracked separately

I want to access a spreadsheet from an App Engine app using the Sheets API, but I wonder how the usage limits are applied to service-accounts.

1. In Cloud Console IAM of the corresponding project, a service-account is created for the app.
2. The Google spreadsheet is shared with the email address of the service-account (with *edit* permission).
3. Code in the app uses service-account from JSON file to authenticate successfully to the Sheets API. No user delegation included.
4. App can successfully write to the spreadsheet with the service-account credentials.

Since these requests are done only with service-account credentials and with no user credentials, I wonder if a service-account in this context is considered as a *"user"* or just as the project (of the app).

**Question:**
Is the *per user limit* applicable, i.e. app would be limited to 100 write requests per 100 seconds. Or are these requests only counted against the *per project limit*, i.e. app could issue up to 500 write requests per 100 seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A service account is a user it has its own Google drive account actually. You shared the sheet with its email address like you would with any other user.

Using a service account is exactly like running as a normal user account the same quota limitations apply.

There is a parameter called [quota user](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/query-parameters)  which can be used to extend the quote but it doesn't work perfectly from behind the same ip address